# Expected value of 2nd-smallest out of 3 random variables

Tags: probability, expectation

I understand how to calculate the expectation of the minimum and the maximum of $n$ random variables, but I'm not sure whether I'm getting the following right.

I'm interested in the expected value of the 2nd-smallest out of 3 I.I.D. random variables with distribution $F$.

Denoting the random variables as $A$, $B$ and $C$, my approach would be to first calculate the distribution of the 2nd-smallest out of 3 as follows:

$$ F_{2/3}(x) = Pr(A \land B < x < C ) + Pr(A \land C < x < B) + Pr (B \land C < x< A) + Pr (A \land B \land C < x)  = 3 F(x)^2(1-F(x)) + F(x)^3 = 3 F(x)^2 - 2 F(x)^3 $$

and then the expectation using

$$ \int x f_{2/3} (x) dx. $$

Is this correct?

Comment: The keyword for these issues is "order statistic" (ill-named because it's a fully probabilistic theory):(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic)

Comment: Note: $\wedge$ is normally used to represent $\min$ as binary operator in this context. You require the $\max$, that is $\vee$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for iid *continuous* random variables, it is so that:  $${F_{(2\setminus 3)}(x)} ~{=~{ {\mathsf P\big((A\vee B)\leqslant x\lt C\big)}+{\mathsf P\big((A\vee C)\leqslant x\lt B\big)}\\+{\mathsf P\big((B\vee C)\leqslant x\lt A)}+{\mathsf P\big((A\vee B\vee C)\leqslant x\big)}}\\=~ 3\, F(x)^2\,\big(1-F(x)\big)~+~ F(x)^3 \\=~ 3\, F(x)^2-2\,F(x)^3}$$

Thus by differentiation:  $$f_{(2\setminus 3)}(x) ~{=~ 6 f(x)\,F(x)-6f(x)\,F(x)^2\\ =~ 3!\, f(x)\,F(x)\,\big(1-F(x)\big)}$$

---

Note: In this context, $\wedge$ and $\vee$ are the binary operators for $\min$ and $\max$ respectively.   You want the $\max$.

Comment: Note that this generalizes to the $k$th-smallest of $n$ random variables: in general we have $f_{k\setminus n}(x) = {n! \over (k-1)! (n-k)!} f(x) F(x)^{k-1} (1-F(x))^{n-k}$.

Comment: The important thing to remember in @Graham Kemp's answer is that you are using a binomial distribution reasoning in $\underbrace{3\, F(x)^2\,\big(1-F(x)\big)}_{3p^2q}~+~ \underbrace{F(x)^3}_{p^3}$ where $q:=1-p$.