# Expected value of 2nd-bigger number out of n independent random variables in uniform distribution [r,1], r>0

Tags: game-theory, order-statistics, auction-theory

I am having a problem on which I have 4 players bidding in second price auction with reserved price (r). I need to find the expected value of 2nd bigger number when there are 3 players or 4 bidding over r, bid>r. For example, if 3 players bids over r, I need to find the expected value of the second bigger bid. So far I've found that when 2 players bids over r the expected value is equal to $a + (b-a)/3$  when we have uniform distribution in [a,b]. So in my example in [r,1] will be equal to $ r + (1-r)/3 $ I need the expected value of 2nd bigger value of n values. Haven't thought a way to do so. Found this but didn't help me [Expected value of 2nd-smallest out of 3 random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2315799/expected-value-of-2nd-smallest-out-of-3-random-variables?noredirect=1&lq=1). Thanks in advance and sorry if my question is amateur.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin Thanks! So far I've found that when 2 players bids over r the expected value is equal to a + (b-a)/3 when we have uniform distribution in [a,b]. I need the expected value of 2nd bigger value of n values. Haven't thought a way to do so. Found this but didn't help me. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2315799/expected-value-of-2nd-smallest-out-of-3-random-variables?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the expected value of the second highest value in $n$ uniform random variables on $[a,b]$ is $a + (b-a)\frac{n-1}{n+1}$.

You can first consider $n$ uniform random variables on $[0,b-a]$, then the pdf of the second highest value is 
$$f(x) = \frac{n!}{(n-2)!}(\frac{x}{b-a})^{n-2}(1-\frac{x}{b-a}),$$
which has mean value $(b-a)(\frac{n-1}{n+1})$.

Maybe you can see https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFfYC.jpg and [Expected value of $2$nd highest draw from uniform dist out of n draws](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3344615/expected-value-of-2nd-highest-draw-from-uniform-dist-out-of-n-draws) for detailed discussion.

Comment: Thank you that works!